# bloom; RuntimeError: Two packages have different version numbers (but it is false)

Tags: ros, git, bloom-release, metapackage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to release a meta package using boom with the following command:

```
bloom-release --rosdistro indigo --track indigo summit_xl_common
```

And after a lot of questions it gives me the following error:

```
==> git-bloom-import-upstream /tmp/tmpUJpJvY/upstream-indigo-1.0.0.tar.gz  --release-version 1.0.0 --replace
Creating upstream branch.
Importing archive into upstream branch...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/git-bloom-import-upstream", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('bloom==0.5.21', 'console_scripts', 'git-bloom-import-upstream')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bloom/commands/git/import_upstream.py", line 391, in main
    args.replace)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bloom/commands/git/import_upstream.py", line 324, in import_upstream
    _, actual_version, _ = get_package_data('upstream')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bloom/packages.py", line 91, in get_package_data
    version = verify_equal_package_versions(packages.values())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/packages.py", line 127, in verify_equal_package_versions
    raise RuntimeError('Two packages have different version numbers (%s != %s):\n- %s\n- %s' % (package.version, version, package.filename, packages[0].filename))
RuntimeError: Two packages have different version numbers (0.0.3 != 1.0.0):
- /tmp/tmp7NakeJ/summit_xl_localization/package.xml
- /tmp/tmp7NakeJ/summit_xl_common/package.xml

<== Error running command '['/usr/bin/git-bloom-import-upstream', '/tmp/tmpUJpJvY/upstream-indigo-1.0.0.tar.gz', '--release-version', '1.0.0', '--replace']'
Release failed, exiting.
```

It says that summit_xl_common and summit_xl_localization have different version numbers, but it is false, you can check [here](https://github.com/RobotnikAutomation/summit_xl_common/blob/indigo-devel/summit_xl_localization/package.xml) that it is version 1.0.0 (same as [summit_xl_common](https://github.com/RobotnikAutomation/summit_xl_common/blob/indigo-devel/summit_xl_common/package.xml)).

Why does it occur? How should I fix it?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237184/bloom;-runtimeerror:-two-packages-have-different-version-numbers-(but-it-is-false)/) by [cvillar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27153/cvillar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-06-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2016-06-16**:
Can you please post the full log, maybe in a gist.github.com? The logs are stored in `~/.bloom_logs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've finally managed to publish the release, it was a problem with the package.xml version pushed with that tag, I deleted it and creted it again and it works.

Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [cvillar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27153/cvillar/) with karma: 16 on 2016-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure exactly why the error is occurring but I do notice that you're using a non-standard version tag, `indigo-1.0.0`. The standard tag would be `1.0.0` It is bad practices and will break a lot of tools' assumptions to have different content with the same version number. Different distros should have different versions series.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-06-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1